# Jenkins Query and Trigger Gerrit Patches

Tags: jenkins, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

I am using Jenkins 'Gerrit Trigger' to configure if there is any patchset uploaded to Gerrit server, then the Jenkins job will be triggered.

But unfortunately, there is some issue that some of the patchsets are not being triggered. I tried to use Jenkins 'Query and Trigger Gerrit Patches' to get those missed patchsets that are not being triggered. And I select one by one to trigger those patchsets manually.

I would like to ask is there any automated way to get those missed patchsets query and run some command to trigger the Jenkins job to run??

Comment: Why some patchsets are not being triggered?

Comment: I'm not sure but sometimes there will have some patches missed to be triggered. it is an intermittent issues

Answer (score 0):

As you are able to use the 'Query and Trigger Gerrit Patches' in Jenkins,
it suggests the problem is related to disconnects or some load on the Jenkins-side
that causes it to miss those triggers.

I suggest reviewing the Jenkins-log, looking for errors related to the Gerrit Trigger.